# Why does my profile 301 votes cast when I do not have the civic duty badge

Tags: bug

My profile is showing 301 votes but I do not have civic duty[image]

EDIT : Now it is saying

[image]

But I still do not have the badge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the Civic Duty badge in your profile now, so the issue is resolved.

There are two factors in play:

1. Badges are issued by a script that runs periodically (at least, this is so for badges that are not tied to a specific post). So there is typically a delay between meeting the criteria for a badge and getting it.
2. The profile pages are not regenerated every time you visit your profile. They are cached on the server for some amount of time. This is why it's possible to be notified of having earned a badge, and still not see it in the profile for a while.